# How to enlarge title font size of nomenclature

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize, nomenclature

I use these codes (in preamble):

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\LARGE\bfseries}
```

That used for customize the font size of "Table of Content" to be LARGE (about 18pt). So that it will be same size as chapter title. I already used the same method for List of Figure and List of Table.

```
\cftloftitlefont
\cftlottitlefont
```

Now, I want to apply the same effect to Nomenclature, but I could not find the right code. Anyone know about it?

Comment: Or, in simple, How to edit the font size of title "Nomenclature" using ERT? any idea?

Answer (score 5):

The Nomenclature is set as a regular chapter; [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) doesn't handle other ad-hoc "List of.."s with specialized commands like `\cft...titlefont`. So, you can patch the chapter command momentarily or just try `{\renewcommand{\Huge}{\LARGE}\printnomenclature}` (note the grouping around the entire command).

`\Huge` is the regular size of the chapter titles (in the standard document classes), which is set in **bold** by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this code:  {\renewcommand{\Huge}{\LARGE}\printnomenclature} does not work. There were two similar page of Nomenclature which make the document ugly.

Comment: Oh, one thing, the same issue with the heading of Bibliography. The font size is smaller that that on the chapter heading. I also want to change the font size bigger. I tried to add (using ERT) : \begin{LARGE} ...... \end{LARGE}, but the entire bibliography and nomenclature font size become LARGE, not only the heading (that is I want). Any idea?

Comment: Finally, I got the code:  \renewcommand{\nomname}{\LARGE Nomenclature}, that solved my problem with Nomenclature heading. Now, the same problem goes to Bibliography heading. I tried to apply above code, the font size of the Bibliography heading was changed but it affect the table of content also. The word "Bibliography" in TOC changed to be bigger also. Any idea?

Comment: @ajwahyudi: `\nomname` *is* the name used for the heading of the Nomenclature. However, it's also used in the page headers and in the ToC (if required). So, using `\renewcommand{\nomname}{\LARGE Nomenclature}` change the font to `\LARGE`, overriding the default `\Huge`, but also affects it wherever `\nomname` is used. I guess you used `\renewcommand{\refname}{\LARGE References}` for your Bibliography?